# VB ComboBox.NewIndex

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

In VB6 I have a line of code that will not convert in .NET, and I am unsure what the correct member should be. The error is is "NewIndex is not a member of system.windows.forms.combobox"

The code:

```
VB6.SetItemData(cboDrawing, cboDrawing.NewIndex, NumericClean(r.Fields.Item("DrawSafeID")))
```

Can someone please tell me what member I should be using?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwbfz5h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @SomeNickName that link that you submitted is for a listbox not a combobox

Comment: No it isn't, it's just a code example, there's no single-referenciation to a listbox, see [here](http://i.imgur.com/MNtp7yA.png) which refers to the first link i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the code to be something like the following:

> VB6.SetItemData(cboDrawing, cboDrawing.Items.Count - 1, NumericClean(r.Fields.Item("DrawSafeID")))

This selects the most recently added Item in the combobox

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fte6kbt2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> NewIndex Property
>
> In Visual Basic 6.0, the NewIndex property was used to retrieve the
>   index of the item most recently added to aComboBox control.
>
> In Visual Basic 2008, the NewIndex property no longer exists. You can
>   use the return value from the Item.Add method to retrieve the index of
>   an item as it is added.